# Updating thousands of mysql rows with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a script with needs to update a value over night - each night.

My mysql db has 119k rows which is grouped into 35k rows.

For each of these rows i need to calculate the highest and the lowest value and the update the row with a new percent difference between these rows.

Right now i can't even execute the update with a limit of 50+

My code:

```
$query_updates = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT partner FROM trolls WHERE GROUP BY partner LIMIT 0, 50") 
    or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_updates)) {

        $query_updates_prices = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
                                                        MIN(partner1) AS p1, 
                                                        MAX(partner2) AS p2, 
                                                        COUNT(partner3) AS p3 
        FROM trolls WHERE partner='". $item["partner"] ."'") 
        or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $partner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_updates_prices);
        $partner1 = $partner["p1"];
        $partner2 = $partner["p2"];
        $difference = $partner1 - $partner2;
        $savings = round($difference / $partner1 * 100);

        $partner3 = $prices["p3"];

        $update_tyre = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE trolls SET 
                                                                        partner1='". $partner1 ."', 
                                                                        partner2='". $partner2 ."', 
                                                                        partner3='". $partner3 ."', 
                                                                        partner4='". $savings ."' 

        WHERE partner='". $item["partner"] ."'") 
        or die(mysqli_error($con));

        echo '<strong>Updated: '. $item["partner"] .'</strong><br>';

    }
```

How can i make this more simple / able to execute?

Comment: `...trolls WHERE GROUP BY partner...` you have a where keyword, but not criterion, this is a syntax error.

Comment: Use a prepare query... but i don't know if it will do the trick. I would consider an only mysql solution without php

Comment: To update value every night you have to make cron job. Agree with @Shadow please correct you query first.

Comment: Create a BTREE index on trolls (partner), that will probably speed up things a little bit, this is the code for creating an index without locking the table: `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IX_TROLLS_PARTNET ON trolls USING btree(partner);`. What is your php.ini `max_execution_time`?

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the cron, also command line running  would help you out as it won't timeout. However you might have problems with group by locking tables. 
To be honest (you won't like this) but if you are doing a group by on a field with a large amount of fields,  then I would say that you have done something wrong.
So I would look at redoing the tables, having a table for 'partner' and then referencing off trolls that would help.

But to give you a solution just to speed this up a touch, move you towards a better database/table setup and to remove the locking problem. I would do this.

Step 1.
Create a table called

```
Partners
Field1: partner_id
Field2: partner
Field3: p1
Field4: p2
Field5: p3
```

Step 2:
Run the query 
SELECT partner FROM trolls (this could be changed in the future to SELECT * FROM partners)

Step 3:
Check are they in Partners - if not insert

Step 4:
Run your

```
SELECT 
MIN(partner1) AS p1, 
MAX(partner2) AS p2, 
COUNT(partner3) AS p3 
FROM trolls WHERE partner='". $item["partner"] ."'
```

Step 5:
Updates the values from this into the Partners table, and (for the time being) update the trolls table.

Done.

Oh and incase it's not already there add in an index to the partners field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do those 2 SELECTs in one:

```
SELECT partner, MIN(partner1) AS p1, MAX(partner2) AS p2, COUNT(partner3) AS p3 
FROM trolls GROUP BY partner LIMIT 0, 50
```

Create a BTREE index on trolls (partner) without locking the table:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IX_TROLLS_PARTNER ON trolls USING btree(partner);
```

If you choose to still do those 2 SELECTs separated, use PDO->prepare instead of PDO->query, [PDO->prepare doc on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information

Maybe change php.ini `max_execution_time` to a higher value if it's too low (I keep it 300 (5 minutes) but each case is a case :P ).